# Unix: Expressing a number in certain digit format padded with zeroes

Tags: shell, unix

How can i express a number with certain number of digits with a command in unix.

Say 7 to be expressed in 6 digits as 000007 and 17 to be 000017. Please let me know if any such command available to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using BASH then you can use `printf` builtin for zero padding:

```
printf "%06d\n" 7
000007

printf "%06d\n" 17
000017
```

To save formatted string in a variable use:

```
printf -v str "%06d\n" 17

echo "$str"
000017
```

If not using BASH then use `awk`:

```
awk -v n=17 'BEGIN{printf "%06d\n", n}'
000017

awk -v n=7 'BEGIN{printf "%06d\n", n}'
000007
```

Comment: There should be no comma after the format string in the shell syntax. `Awk` is not required even if `bash` is not used.

Comment: Thanks and good point, comma was copy/paste mistake (corrected)

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether you are using `bash` or not, but assuming you are running on a Unix/Unix like OS, `printf` will work, being a mandatory standalone POSIX utility.

```
printf "%06d\n" 7
```